# IOS App - scores of short sound files vs. a few larger files

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have an IOS app where I will end up with several hundred short very short sounds- most are voiced words, though there will be some sound effects as well.

If I have one file per sound, I only need to store the file name per sound name. If I have multiple sounds in a file, I need to store the file name, starting point and duration for each sound name.

While recording the narrator reads several words with pauses in between and records into one file (I need to break this up into multiple files if needed).

The files are not bundled with the app - based on user preferences, the files are downloaded and stored on the device.  Think of it as user chooses a game level, and all the sound and image files associated are downloaded.

My question is in regard to size and performance of the app. Is one way better than the other - say 600 sound files or 30 files with 20 sounds each - and why is one way better than the other?

I can go with one file for each sound or have large sound file and play from a specific time in the file for the length of the sound. I have tested code both ways and it produced the sound correctly.

I understand the trade-offs during coding and preparing the audio files. But I do not have a feel for app size, performance etc. I would appreciate any input.